# jQuery dropdown menu. Page marker not working correctly - or how i want it to

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

The navbar doesn't look exactly the same as what i have on my own side since i have background images and such - but the navbar itself works perfectly even though on jsfiddle it looks a little funky.

The problem I'm having is that my visual marker for whenever i'm on a page, which cant be seen on jsFiddle very well or at all since i can't click on other pages).  I'm able to get the visual marker to work on the specific page that i click but only of that specific click, what i'm trying to achieve is a visual marker of where you are no matter how far deep down you are in the pages (whether ul li a or ul li > ul li a or even ul li > ul li > ul li a). for instance.

(need to see Jsfiddle to understand what i'm saying) If i hover over "Web", there is a drop-down. I then proceed to go down to "Web-215" where there is another dropdown where I decide i want to navigate to the "jQuery" page.

What is currently happening is : When i click on "jQuery" that that single item is being given an id of 'current'. which changes the look. But it's only doing it to that single item.

What I want it to do is this: If i click on just "Web" it will add attribute to just "Web" but if i click on "Web > Web-215" or anything in that folder - then it will highlight Web AND web-215. And also - If i click on 'jQuery' which is a third level li to 'Web-215', then all three will have attribute 'current' selected. and should i pick different paths or links it should follow those rules.

I'm not sure where I need to go with it but here is the live example: http://jsfiddle.net/knvH4/2/

this is where I think the problem somewhere lays Line 16 in the javascript in the jsfiddle

```
function youAreHere() {
var pathName = $(location).attr('pathname');
var curPage = pathName.substring(pathName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
$('a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == curPage) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'current');
    } else if (curPage == '') {
        $('a:first').attr('id', 'current');
    }
}); //END function
```

what is it that I need to do to make it so that all will be given the attribute of (or id) of 'current' and not just the one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was my solution to my problem that I came up with - Thank you for the people who gave me input!

```
function youAreHere() {
var pathName = $(location).attr('pathname');
var curPage = pathName.substring(pathName.lastIndexOf('/')+1, pathName.lastIndexOf('.'));
$('a').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var path = href.substring(0, href.lastIndexOf('.'));
    if(curPage.indexOf(path) !== -1) {
        $(this).addClass('current');
    } else if (curPage == '') {
        $('a:first').addClass('current');
    }
});//END function
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing to note is that you should never give more than one element on a page the same id. Use a class instead.

If you're having success with highlighting the current page item, but not it's parents, you can use the jQuery's `closest()` method and add the "current" class to it (this means changing the css to reflect a class instead of id as well). I haven't tested the below code, but I think it will help:

```
if ($(this).attr('href') == curPage) {
    $(this).addClass('current');

    //if inside child menu, highlight parent anchor
    if($(this).closest('ul').siblings('a').length){
        $(this).closest('ul').siblings('a').addClass('current');

        //if inside grandchild menu, highlight grandparent anchor as well
        if($(this).closest('ul').siblings('a').closest('ul').siblings('a').length){
            $(this).closest('ul').siblings('a').closest('ul').siblings('a').addClass('current');
        }
    }
} else if (curPage == '') {
    $('a:first').addClass('current');
}
```

Ideally, you'd add `id`s to each of the `ul`s instead of traversing upward through the dom.